# Spring multiple @PathVariable failure

Tags: spring

when I try calling this endpoint with just this endpoint: /api/v1/data/{provider}/{subject} (I removed @pathvariable dataset parameter when I got rid of the dataset path) I am able to successfully call my API. However, when I add an additional pathvariable (dataset in this case), I can't seem to hit my endpoint anymore. Is there some restriction on number of path variables? Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
@GetMapping("/api/v1/data/{provider}/{subject}/{dataset}")
public List<List<String>> getEDXDatasetHead(
            @PathVariable final String provider,
            @PathVariable final String subject,
            @PathVariable final String dataset,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "date") final String date
)
```

https://localhost:8443/api/v1/data/testprovider/testsubject/testdataset
@GetMapping("/api/v1/data/{provider}/{subject}/{dataset}")

Comment: Let me check if I understood this right. You have the endpoint configured as `@GetMapping("/api/v1/data/{provider}/{subject}/{dataset}")` and you call `/api/v1/dataset/{provider}/{subject}` and it does not work? Can you please be a little bit clearer?

Comment: Sure. The endpoint is @GetMapping("/api/v1/data/{provider}/{subject}/{dataset}")
And I call: localhoststuff: api/v1/data/testprovider/testsubject/testdataset
I can verify that my localhost port is correct because I can hit other endpoints.

Comment: Resolved. Due to a bug from dependency

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular limit on number of PathVariable that you can add to a method.

But if you want to call your API with many different number of PathVariables you need to add a method for each of them, otherwise spring is not able to understand that you are calling the same method with a shorter number of path variables:

```
@GetMapping("/api/v1/data/{provider}/{subject}/{dataset}")
public List<List<String>> getEDXDatasetHead(
            @PathVariable final String provider,
            @PathVariable final String subject,
            @PathVariable final String dataset,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "date") final String date
) 


...


@GetMapping("/api/v1/data/{provider}/{subject}")
public List<List<String>> getEDXDatasetHead(
            @PathVariable final String provider,
            @PathVariable final String subject,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "date") final String date
) 

...


@GetMapping("/api/v1/data/{provider}")
public List<List<String>> getEDXDatasetHead(
            @PathVariable final String provider,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "date") final String date
)
```

Note: spring doesn't have a particular limitation on the number of PathVariable that can be used in a method. But there are limitations on:

- the size of the generated url (if too long not all browser handle it correctly)
- the format of the url (check if you url encoded the path variables when you build the url on the client side)

Comment: I agree with you on that, but I don't need to overload and only have one method with one endpoint (with all the required {} path formatting. I pretty much want that first method that you linked but when I try to hit that endpoint, it just fails.

Comment: post the url that fails and the the corresponding  @GetMapping path

Comment: Sorry for delay, edited the urls into the question

Comment: @alexst your update seems correct, but differs from the original code. Are you using @GetMapping("/api/v1/**data**/{provider}/{subject}/{dataset}") or @GetMapping("/api/v1/**edx**/{provider}/{subject}/{dataset}") ?

Comment: I'm using "data". Was just trying something else in IDE but didn't change back. Apologies.